# public_html folder on webserver

Tags: php, linux

I created a public_html folder on my webserver at home and when I try to open php files on the browser tries to download the file instead of displaying.  HTML files open fine and when i move the php file to /var/www it works fine.  Any help would be great, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog post](http://devplant.net/2010/05/04/linux-php-not-working-in-userdir-public_html/) describes a case where the Apache config is specifically disabling PHP on those folders, in which case you need to find your Apache configuration file and remove/comment-out something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Note that if you do this you had better trust every single user on your machine pretty well, since there's nothing stopping a user from creating a PHP file which can run as your apache user and do a lot of damage.

Answer (score 1):

This is mos likely because you haven't setup the server to handle PHP files with PHP. Following this guide should help: http://www.lamphowto.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure apache is configured to pass off .php files to mod_php for that folder.

See: http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html